# How can I render custom field values from a ParseObject in cshtml using ASP.NET Razor Pages?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, parse-platform, parse-dotnet-sdk

I'm using Razor Pages with ASP.NET to render data to my cshtml:

```
@* Iterate over Yeet collection *@
@foreach (var yeet in Model.YeetsList)
{
    <p>@yeet.Keys.1.value</p><br />
}
```

I'm iterating over a List called YeetsList that contains some ParseObject objects.

ParseObjects don't have the custom field accessors one would need to render anything more than basic ParseObject data such as ObjectId, CreatedAt, UpdatedAt, etc., but I figured I could just render these (private) fields anyway by printing the value of the Key I want according to this:

[image]

I get the following:

[image]

What I want is the actual value of "notificationText". How can I retrieve this and render it without going through the hassle of creating a local data model? I  really don't want to create a proper app at the moment. I just want to print the value of "notificationText" that is contained in the object.

Comment: `<p>@yeet.Keys.ElementAt(1)</p>` should do (that will be name, not value, since as I understand you need a name).

Comment: And if you need value, then just `<p>@yeet["notificationText"]</p>`

Comment: @Evk Thank you. I was looking for the value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use something like this , this might help

```
   @foreach (var yeet in Model.YeetsList)
    {
       @foreach (string key in yeet.Keys)
        {
           <p>@yeet[key].value</p><br />
        }    
    }
```

Comment: Is there a way to display the length if one of the values is a List?

For example, ``@yeet["likesArray"].size()``?

Comment: You need to `typecast` before to check the size , because compiler dont know the  `value` of particular `key` is of which type, and also can you vote up the answer if it helps you